# Android studio/SDK gone dead after sudden PC power off

Tags: java, android, android-studio, sdk

It was working fine till my PC lost power suddenly.

The whole project went dead, tools are not identifying android APIs or even the internal classes of the project.

[image]

The build gradle is below :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.XXXXX"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }



  compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }
}



dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1'
    compile 'fr.avianey.com.viewpagerindicator:library:2.4.1@aar'
    compile 'uk.co.chrisjenx:calligraphy:2.1.0'
}
```

System/IDE configurations are as below:

- Android Studio 1.5.1
- stable channel
- Windows 7
- JDK 7

I tried the following :

1. Create new project, same error
2. Open old working projects
3. Reinstall JDK and setting JAVA-Home
4. Delete and reinstall build tools and SDK I am working with
5. Open Android Studio as Administrator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I  tried the following;
1- erase all android studio files, redownload and setup ... Didn't work
2- created new project using eclipse and it worked fine, then the problem wasn't in the JDK, SDK or Android studio

> The Solution was to Set up new Windows